# Error while creating Asset "ValidationException: Unexpected properties for type org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddAsset: registryType, registryId"

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm new to Hyperledger Composer. I'm following composer tutorial of how to interact with other business network
[hyperledger_composer_tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/invoke-composer-network)

I have followed the step 1,2,3 mention in the tutorial. While i am trying to perform step 4: Create the assest

I am able to create participant in business network A.
**I am getting error while creating asset in business network A**

```
ValidationException: Unexpected properties for type org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddAsset: registryType, registryId
```

[image: error image]

here is my code

Network A

```
/**
 * My commodity trading network
 */
namespace org.example.mynetwork
asset Commodity identified by tradingSymbol {
    o String tradingSymbol
    o String description
    o String mainExchange
    o Double quantity
    --> Trader owner
}
participant Trader identified by tradeId {
    o String tradeId
    o String firstName
    o String lastName
}
transaction Trade {
    --> Commodity commodity
    --> Trader newOwner
}

2) logic.js

        /**
         * Track the trade of a commodity from one trader to another
         * @param {org.example.mynetwork.Trade} trade - the trade to be processed
         * @transaction
         */
        async function tradeCommodity(trade) {
            trade.commodity.owner = trade.newOwner;

            const otherNetworkData = await getNativeAPI().invokeChaincode('other-tutorial-network', ['getResourceInRegistry', 'Asset', 'org.example.mynetwork.Commodity', trade.commodity.tradingSymbol], 'composerchannel');                    
            const stringAsset = new Buffer(otherNetworkData.payload.toArrayBuffer()).toString('utf8');
            const asset = getSerializer().fromJSON(JSON.parse(stringAsset));

            trade.commodity.quantity = asset.quantity;

            const assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.mynetwork.Commodity');
            await assetRegistry.update(trade.commodity);
        }
```

Network B

```
/**
 * My commodity trading network
 */
namespace org.example.mynetwork
asset Commodity identified by tradingSymbol {
    o String tradingSymbol
    o String description
    o String mainExchange
    o Double quantity
    --> Trader owner
}
participant Trader identified by tradeId {
    o String tradeId
    o String firstName
    o String lastName
}
transaction Trade {
    --> Commodity commodity
    --> Trader newOwner
}
2) logic.js

/**
 * Track the trade of a commodity from one trader to another
 * @param {org.example.mynetwork.Trade} trade - the trade to be processed
 * @transaction
 */
async function tradeCommodity(trade) {
    trade.commodity.owner = trade.newOwner;
    let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.mynetwork.Commodity');
    await assetRegistry.update(trade.commodity);
}
```

How do i resolve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the JSON that you are providing as an input in the command line could be wrong, Since you are adding an Asset of type Commodity.

Try this command instead

```
composer transaction submit --card networkA -d '{"$class": "org.example.mynetwork.Commodity","tradingSymbol": "Ag","owner": "resource: org.example.mynetwork.Trader#bob@example.com","description": "Some", "mainExchange": "exhange","quantity": 25}'
```